# Reverting data using sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have been staring at this code for a while now. Researching alternatives but they dont seem to work. Please tell me that i have looked over something little.

```
-(void)revertData
{   
if(revertStmt == nil) {
    const char *sql = "select signature, sigdate from signatureDB where id = ?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &revertStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        UIActionSheet *msg = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database)] 
                              delegate:nil 
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil  destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
        [msg showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window];
    }
}

sqlite3_bind_int(revertStmt, 0, myID);

if(SQLITE_DONE == sqlite3_step(revertStmt)) {

     self.signature = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(revertStmt, 0)];
     self.sigdate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(revertStmt, 1)];
}
sqlite3_reset(revertStmt);

}
```

Comment: May I ask what it does that is wrong and what it should be doing?

Comment: It errors when i make the sqlite3_column_text(revertStmt, 0) call it acts like it is coming up null and throughs a SIGABRT but i've made the call to the sqlite database directly it returns the proper values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems;

1) You seem to have a problem in your sqlite3_bind_int statement, you pass in 0 as an index while the documentation states

> The second argument is the index of the SQL parameter to be set. The
>   leftmost SQL parameter has an index of 1.

2) You check if the return value from sqlite3_step is SQLITE_DONE (which means it has no more rows, in this case none at all since the id isn't set due to problem 1). sqlite_column_* is only valid if the return value is SQLITE_ROW, so your call to sqlite3_column_text will blow up.